# How can I diagnose a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, dns

From about a week ago, I started getting overall slowness when connected to WiFi, and ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors from every page, seemingly at random, using chrome or firefox or when using any other device.

[image: Chrome's ERR_CONNECTION_RESET]

At first, I suspected I had a DNS, even though I'm using Google's Free DNS.

Even SSH connections fail sometimes, but if I retry, they succeed.

[image: SSH error]

How can I diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try repairing Winsock & DNS Cache to clear the stored DNS cache in Windows. Sometimes when DNS becomes corrupt you will not be able to get to some sites. 
Flushing and rebuilding the DNS will fix that problem additionally it also resets winsock entries & resets TCP/IP stack.

You can try these commands in command prompt as admin

```
netsh winsock reset all
netsh int 6to4 reset all
netsh int ipv4 reset all
netsh int ipv6 reset all
netsh int httpstunnel reset all
netsh int isatap reset all
netsh int portproxy reset all
netsh int tcp reset all
netsh int teredo reset all
```

Comment: None of those commands flush the DNS. - Flush DNS resolver cache: 

 `ipconfig /flushdns`

- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases: 

 `ipconfig /registerdns`

- Flush routing table (reboot required):

 `route /f`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I think the problem might lie somewhere else, as this behavior is present in several devices... I have a windows notebook, a linux one, and several phones